# String Splitting a column into multiple columns

Tags: r

Hi I have question regarding R Programming, I am a newbie in R.
I have a dataset in excel with a particular column having values as such.

```
123456
123456789
123456789123
```

Now my requirement is to get values in multiples of 3 and split into different columns.
For eg. My first row would be splitting into 2 columns and second row into 3 columns

```
colA colB colC
123  456
123  456  789
```

The desired output:

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few solutions.  The first 5 do not use any packages.  `nc` (number of columns) and `cn` (column names) defined in (1) are used in the others as well.

**1) read.fwf** Using the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end count the maximum number of characters in a line and divide by 3 to get the number of columns `nc`.  Next compute the column names `cn`.  Finally use `read.fwf` to read them in. No packages are used.

```
nc <- max(nchar(DF[[1]]))/3
cn <- paste0("col", head(LETTERS, nc))
read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(DF[[1]])), rep(3, length = nc),
   col.names = cn)
```

giving:

```
  colA colB colC colD
1  123  456   NA   NA
2  123  456  789   NA
3  123  456  789  123
```

**2) formatC** A variation on the above would be to use `formatC` to insert commas after every 3 characters giving the character vector `ch` and then read that in using `read.csv`.

```
ch <- formatC(DF[[1]], format= "f", digits = 0, big.mark = ",")
read.csv(text = ch, header = FALSE, col.names = cn)
```

**3) strsplit** Another variation would be to split the column using `strsplit` and the indicated regular expression to split by and then use toString to put the split components into a comma separated string vector, `ch`.  Finally use `read.csv` as before.

```
ch <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(DF[[1]]), "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE), toString)
read.csv(text = ch, header = FALSE, col.names = cn)
```

**4) gsub**  Yet another variation is to use `gsub` to insert commas every 3 characters and then use `read.csv` as in (2) and (3).

```
ch <- gsub("(...)(?=.)", "\\1,", DF[[1]], perl = TRUE)
read.csv(text = ch, header = FALSE, col.names = cn)
```

**5) strcapture**  This one does not use any read.* routine.  It also uses only base R.

```
strcapture(strrep("(...)?", nc), DF[[1]], setNames(double(nc), cn))
```

**6) strapplyc** This is the only variation that uses a package.  `strapplyc` can be used to pick off successive 3 character subsets.  It uses a simpler regular expression than some of our other solutions.  `read.csv` is used as in some of the other solutions.

```
library(gsubfn)

ch <- sapply(strapplyc(DF[[1]], "..."), toString)
read.csv(text = ch, header = FALSE, col.names = cn)
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
123456
123456789
123456789123"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  separate(a, into = c('b', 'c', 'd'), sep= c(3, 6), remove = FALSE)
#          a   b   c   d
#1       123 123        
#2    123456 123 456    
#3 123456789 123 456 789
```

Using `convert=TRUE`, changes the `type` of the column automatically

```
df %>% 
   separate(a, into = c('b', 'c', 'd'), sep= c(3, 6), 
          remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame (a = c(123,123456,123456789))
```

Answer (score 1):

using library data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, tstrsplit(df1$col1, "(?:.{3}+\\K)", perl = TRUE)] # change {3} to other numbers if you don't want to split after every 3.

#    V1  V2   V3   V4
#1: 123 456 <NA> <NA>
#2: 123 456  789 <NA>
#3: 123 456  789  123
```

---

data:

```
df1<-
structure(list(col1 = c("123456", "123456789", "123456789123"
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , this was a lot of help

Comment: Can you please let me know how does (?:.{3}+\\K) work?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a method that involves less repetition but one option may be

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame (a = c(123,123456,123456789))

df %>%
  mutate(b = substr(a, 0,3),
         c = substr(a, 4,6),
         d = substr(a, 7,9))

          a   b   c   d
1       123 123        
2    123456 123 456    
3 123456789 123 456 789
```